# How to call cvMorphologyEx in openCV in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

i need to call cvMorphologyEx in my image processing project and i do it using this line.

```
cvMorphologyEx(src1,dest1,NULL,NULL,CV_MOP_OPEN);
```

It compiles fine but while running it gives me this error

> OpenCV Error: Bad flag (parameter or structure field) (Unrecognized or unsupport
>   ed array type) in unknown function, file ........\ocv\opencv\src\cxcore\cxarr
>   ay.cpp, line 2476

I am sure the problem is in the third and fourth arguments but the documentation says that they are optional.

If you need anymore details please tell me.

Thanks,

Bye

Comment: You are right the 4th argument have to be kernel, but anyway you should be aware that this function have changed a lot in OpenCV 4.4.0 as it became 4 parameters only cv::morphologyEx(In_Mat_image, Out_Mat_image, CV_MOP_OPEN, image_Kernel);

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an IplConvKernel and pass it to the function, otherwise cvMorphologyEx dose not know the size and the shape of the structuring element so it can no do any processing.

```
int filterSize = 5;
IplConvKernel *convKernel = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(filterSize, filterSize, (filterSize - 1) / 2, (filterSize - 1) / 2, CV_SHAPE_RECT, NULL);

cvMorphologyEx(src1, dest1, NULL, convKernel, CV_MOP_OPEN);
```

Take care the structuring element is not optional!